# GTK: TreeModel::iter_next returns false when there are more elements

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I have a TreeView with a TreeStore, and it looks like this:

[image]

I get the selected row from the `TreeView` by calling `get_selection` and calling `get_selected` on the resulting `TreeSelection`. From this I obtain a `TreeIter` which should point to the selected row.

I expect either `iter_next` or `iter_prev` (from TreeModel) to be successful since there is another row *at the same level*, namely `Hello`. **However, calling either of those iter functions on the selected iter returns false.**

Have I misunderstood something?
The documentation for `TreeModel::iter_next` states:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the node following iter at the current level.

And `Hello` and `Hello 2` are evidently on the same level.

Comment: MCVE or at least some code could help a lot. Did you change selection mode to MULTIPLE?

Comment: Selection mode is Single. Here is some relevant code - using Rust bindings: https://bpaste.net/show/e53bcd512f4a . `self.model.tree` is a `TreeStore`.

Comment: I found the problem. I listen for `Ctrl+Up` to do the operation I mentioned. However, it seems like GTK first acts according to the `Up` keypress so that when my `node_up` function is called, the focus has changed to the `Help` node. Any idea how I can make it ignore `Up` when it is accompanied with `Ctrl`?

Comment: (I found an answer to that question as well. And I meant `Shift+Up`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I listen for Shift+Up to do the operation I mentioned. However, it seems like GTK first acts according to the Up keypress so that when my node_up function is called, the focus has changed to the Help node.